# Recurring Payment Code using PAYPAL

Tags: c#, razor, paypal, paypal-sandbox

In our application we are having monthly subscription so on last date of the month amount should transfer from UserAccount to CompanyAccount?
How to do this after equal frequency?Like Mothly,Quaterly etc.
Please Help US.........

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Windows task scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) to call specific web page or exe which will do transfer.
Set up one task scheduler to call transfer monthly and second to call quarterly.